# Linderdaum BuildAndroid resolve to a path with no project.properties file

Tags: android, ant, linderdaum

I get this error when doing `ant copy-common-media debug` in Cygwin:

```
C:\android\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:573: ..\..\BuildAndroid resolve to a path with no project.properties file for project D:\LinderdaumSDK\Apps\MyApps
```

I checked and a project.properties file does exist at that location. I followed all the instructions in a !README-BUILD-ANDROID.txt but the error still exists. I'm using Android API level 13, SDK Tools 24.4.1, and Build Tools 27.0.3. How to fix this please?

Comment: Do you have a `project.properties` file in your folder?

Comment: "I checked and a project.properties file does exist at that location."